# Calculate difference between two values in jquery

Tags: jquery

How do I calculate the difference between the top one and the bottom one with jquery?

```
<span class="field-content">9.75</span>
<span class="field-content">4.75</span>
```

Comment: Are these the only `.field-content` in your HTML?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var diff = Number($(".field-content:first").text()) - Number($(".field-content:last").text())
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Zk285/

You can do it that way.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming these are the only objects with class="field-content" in your page, you could do this.  I generally find it wise not to run the same selector over and over again so here, I run it once and then pull items out of it to do the substraction.

```
var items = $(".field-content");
var diff = Number(items.eq(0).text()) - Number(items.eq(1).text());
```

If there are other items with that class, then you'd need to include other items in the selector to select just these two items.